# Segmentation fault in Z3 (Haskell)

Tags: c, haskell, segmentation-fault, z3

I'm using Haskell to create some Z3 formulas. When I try to run the following code I get segmentation fault (although other examples made by me work great). Does anybody know if that is a bug in Z3? The API used in Haskell is a mirror of the C API names:

```
{-# LANGUAGE NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TupleSections #-}

import Z3.Monad
import Control.Monad.IO.Class
import Control.Applicative
import Data.Traversable
import Prelude hiding (sequence)

main = do
    out <- evalZ3 $ do
        is  <- mkIntSort
        _3  <- mkInteger 3
        _5  <- mkInteger 5
        _10 <- mkInteger 10
        x   <- mkFreshIntVar "x"
        y   <- mkFreshIntVar "y"
        y2  <- mkBvmul y y

        assert =<< mkAnd =<< sequence
            [ mkEq x y2
            ]
        return ()

    print "end"
```

Comment: Segmentation fault is clearly caused by a bug. Probably you should report it to the devs.

Comment: @EugeneSh. In a standard library yes, but looking at similar problems (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9059923/z3-segmentation-fault?rq=1) it seems that segmentation faults in S3 are used sometimes to denote an obsolete API or wrong usage ... heh ;)

Comment: Anyway I've just reported it here: https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/issues/153

Comment: Still, the incorrect usage should yield an error correctly handled, not SEGFAULT. It is a bug anyway..

Comment: I know, I know, I was laughing reading that reply from S3 devs :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug in our library. In 4.0.0 we introduced automatic memory management, but we missed the interaction with error handling. It seems that memory management code executes before error handling code. Thus, when `mkBVmul` returns, memory management code tries to increment the reference count of the result object, which turns to be *null*, before the library knows that there was an error.

I have created an issue for this (cf. https://bitbucket.org/iago/z3-haskell/issues/5/segmentation-fault-due-to-type-error), and I will look into solving it soon. But we would highly appreciate that you report to us segmentation faults in the future. Today we don't use this library at work so, even though I do maintain it, and I do try to help whoever wants to contribute, I mostly rely on users to report errors and contribute with patches.

That being said, once the bug is fixed, what you will get is a Haskell exception carrying the error code *Z3_SORT_ERROR*. The fact that *z3-haskell* bindings provide little type-safety is a design decision. Writing a type-safe Z3 API is non-trivial and requires quite a bit of type hackery and a few GHC extensions. Our target users are tool writers who use Z3 as a backend. Most of them don't want to deal with marshaling and memory management themselves, but still want low-level access to Z3's API.

We don't expect people to write SMT problems directly using our bindings, *sbv* is more suitable for that. It's certainly possible to create a type-safe wrapper for *z3-haskell*, as a separate package. I have this in my to-do list, I just didn't find the time for it.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help @iago. So does it mean that Z3 is no longer used in Microsoft? Are there any reasons behind it? Does it have any consequences regarding the future of Z3 development?

Comment: I think you understood me wrong. David and I (the authors of the Haskell bindings) are not working for Microsoft. We created this project because Microsoft does not provide official bindings for Haskell, our bindings are unofficial. As far as I can tell Z3 is a very active project within Microsoft Research.

Comment: Having clarified this, the fact that we don't use Haskell+Z3 at work anymore, means that we don't actively develop the *z3-haskell* bindings that much, however, we do actively maintain them. (In fact, I'm discussing the bug right now with David.) At least once a year we release a new version with enhancements and better coverage of the API, but the patches mostly come from users of the library. The people developing [Boogaloo](http://rise4fun.com/Boogaloo) for instance, have made quite a few contributions.

Comment: Ahh got it. I'm sorry I was sure you are the developer and maintainer of Z3. Sorry for the confusion!

Answer (score 1):

You should really be reporting this to the Haskell Z3 package maintainers; as they should protect from this sort of usage in the first place. You can find their contact info on: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/z3